# iio-sensor-proxy not working correctly

Tags: gnome, 19.10, touchscreen, udev, sensors

I am trying to install Ubuntu 19:10 on a Medion 3221 - MD 61167 laptop, but I'm have truble with cofiguring iio-sensor-proxy.

When I boot Into Ubuntu live session the screen orientation is to the left, although the laptop is laying flat on the table.

I have followed the instructions provided on the github webpage: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/hwdb.d/60-sensor.hwdb

1. I created a hwdb file at /etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-sensor-local.hwdb
2. Inside the file I added two lines:

```
sensor:modalias:acpi:KIOX010A*:dmi:*:svnMEDION:pnE3221MD61167:*
 ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX=0, -1, 0; -1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1
```

3. Then i updated systemd hwdb with:

```
systemd-hwdb update
udevadm trigger -v -p DEVNAME=/dev/iio:device0
```

Unfortunetly the Issue is still present.

Edit:

I have tried changing the values inside the ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX, using other sensor modalias value that belong to similar laptop models in the hwdb file and logging out of gnome session, but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: My device has the same orientation issue and I just removed `iio-sensor-proxy` completely.